# What does FilePickerExternalImageSearchEnabled tenant property do?

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, governance

Does anyone know what `FilePickerExternalImageSearchEnabled` tenant property is?

```
Connect-SPOService -Url https://contoso-admin.sharepoint.com/
$tenant = Get-SPOTenant
$tenant.FilePickerExternalImageSearchEnabled
```

SharePoint Online Documentation isn't super helpful in answering this question. Is there any insight into what this setting is?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the `FilePickerExternalImageSearchEnabled` is set to `true`, which is the default setting, then any time a content editor is using the modern interface to choose an image, for example, in a "hero" webpart, or simply "image" webpart, they are presented with a dialog that allows the user to choose from "Recent" images, perform a "Web search" for images, look in "OneDrive" for existing images, look in the current "Site", "Upload" a new file from their hard drive, or paste in a "Link" to an existing image.  See the following screenshot of the Image Picker with the "Web Search" option selected.

[image: Screen shot of Image Search File Picker]

When this setting is set to `false`, using `set-spotenant -FilePickerExternalImageSearchEnabled $false`, the "Web Search" option is no longer visible in this commonly used Image Picker dialog.  See the image screenshot below.

Note, that like most tenant-level settings, it can take 5 minutes or more before each site in the tenant picks up the new setting.  Also, to see the new value with `get-spoTenant` immediately after the change, you would need to either start a new PowerShell session or execute `disconnect-sponline` and then re-connect.

[image: Screenshot of Image Picker without Web Search]

Comment: Thank you so much, willman!

Answer (score 0):

According to the official documentation given for PnP Office 365 CLI at: [SPO Tenant Settings Set](https://pnp.github.io/office365-cli/cmd/spo/tenant/tenant-settings-set/),

`FilePickerExternalImageSearchEnabled` is a boolean property of global tenant settings which **Enables file picker external image search**.

Allowed values for `FilePickerExternalImageSearchEnabled` are `true` and `false`.

Comment: Thank you, Ganesh, can you, please explain what the setting is doing exactly?